# Compiler design: best way to store function signatures?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am planning on storing all the function signatures which allows overloading.
Right now I have a nested HashMap that looks something like this:

`HashMap<String,HashMap<ArrayList<Type>,Object>>`

Where the first key, `String`, contains the name of the function. The second key, `ArrayList<Type>`, contains parameter data types. Now, I know using ArrayList as a key is a terrible practice, so I wonder if there is a better solution to store the function signatures?

Comment: I would wrap the ArrayList in its own class, but apart from using ASM classes or so, it looks fine. Worrying is that one does not use the inner class as a map, but for iteration only, for comparing with subtypes. So maybe a somehow ordered map: TreeMap/LinkedHashMap.

Comment: what is the problem to have ArrayList as a key? Hashcode not cached? First make sure it is so and affects performance, and then wrap in a class with cached hashcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design is fine. I ended up keeping this design.